# Character count in string

Tags: python

```
def charcount(stri):
    for i in stri:
        count = 0
        for j in stri:
            if stri[i] == stri[j]:
                count += 1
```

I am new to python and currently learning string operations, can anyone tell me what is wrong in this program? The function tries to print a count of each character in given string.

For eg: string ="There is shadow behind you"
I want to count how many times each character have come in string

Comment: Please be careful to properly format python code in a question. Unformatted python is meaningless. I formatted it for you (leaving it exactly how you had it). That said: Can you explain what you're observing? And what you expect (e.g. sample input and output)? Right now it's just "here's my code - debug it for me." Please edit your question to be more specific.

Comment: May I know what are you trying to achieve in your code, as you are checking if stri[i] == stri[j]? you can edit your question properly along with a example and expected output

Comment: `i` and `j` are not indices but characters out of `stri`. That is how `for` loops work in python. Therefore you want to directly compare `i` to `j`. Also , if you want something printed, typically you'll have to make a `print` statement.

Comment: What is your expected output? Just a bunch of counts, or pairs of character and count?

Answer (score 7):

Counting characters in a string can be done with the [`Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class like:

#### Code:

```
from collections import Counter

def charcount(stri):
    return Counter(stri)

print(charcount('The function try to print count of each character '
                'in given string . Please help'))
```

#### Results:

```
Counter({' ': 14, 'e': 7, 'n': 7, 't': 7, 'c': 5, 'i': 5, 
         'r': 5, 'h': 4, 'o': 4, 'a': 4, 'f': 2, 'u': 2, 
         'p': 2, 'g': 2, 's': 2, 'l': 2, 'T': 1, 'y': 1, 
         'v': 1, '.': 1, 'P': 1})
```

Comment: in_l = ','.join(str(input('Put a string: '))).split(',')
d1={}
for i in set(in_l):
    d1[i] = in_l.count(i)
print(d1)

Answer (score 1):

**Feedback on code:**

In these lines:

```
for i in stri:
    count = 0
    for j in stri:
```

The outer loop is looping over each character in `stri`, and the inner loop is looping over every character in `stri`. This is like a Cartesian product of the elements in the list, and is not necessary here.

Secondly, in this line:

```
if stri[i] == stri[j]:
```

You are accessing `stri` by its indices, but `i` and `j` are not indices, they are the characters themselves. So treating them as indices does not work here, since characters are not valid indices for lists. If you wanted to access just the indices, you could access them with `range(len())`:

```
for i in range(len(stri)):
    count = 0
    for j in range(len(stri)):
        if stri[i] == stri[j]:
```

Or if you want to access the elements and their indices, you can use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Having said this, your approach is too complicated and needs to be redone. You need to group your characters and count them. Using nested loops is overkill here.

**Alternative approaches:**

There are lots of better ways to do this such as using [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and dictionaries. These data structures are very good for counting.

Since it also looks like your struggling with loops, I suggest going back to the basics, and then attempt doing this problem with a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Counting each characters in a string

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> string ="There is shadow behind you"
>>> Counter(string)
Counter({' ': 4, 'h': 3, 'e': 3, 'i': 2, 's': 2, 'd': 2, 'o': 2, 'T': 1, 'r': 
1, 'a': 1, 'w': 1, 'b': 1, 'n': 1, 'y': 1, 'u': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do. Iterate through the input string and use a hash to keep track of the counts. In python, the basic hash is a dictionary.

```
def charCounter(string):
    d = {} # initialize a new dictionary
    for s in string:
        if s not in d:
            d[s] = 1
        else:
            d[s] += 1
    return d

print charCounter("apple") 
# returns {'a': 1, 'p': 2, 'e': 1, 'l': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just little modification in your solution**

first you are looping wrong:-

**Take a look:-**

```
def charcount(stri):
    d = {}
    for i in stri:

        if i in d:
            d[i] = d[i] +1
        else:
          d[i] = 1
    return d

print (charcount("hello")) #expected outpu
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any import :

```
def charcount(string):
        occurenceDict = dict()
        for char in string:
            if char not in occurenceDict:
                occurenceDict[char] = 1
            else :
                occurenceDict[char] += 1
        return(occurenceDict)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code.

```py
in_l = ','.join(str(input('Put a string: '))).split(',')
d1={}
for i in set(in_l):
    d1[i] = in_l.count(i)
print(d1)
```

Answer (score 0):

public class Z {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int count=0;

    String str="aabaaaababa";

    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++) {

        if(str.charAt(i)=='a') {

            count++;
            
        }

    }

    System.out.println(count);

}
```

}

Comment: This is not Python. The question is specifically about Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just split by the char and take the length -1:

```
def charCounter(string,char):
    return len(string.split(char))-1
```